# Apache James 3 unexpectedly quits after few seconds

Tags: jaxb, james

I always get this whenever I try to add domain

```
Error connecting to remote JMX agent : Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)]
usage: java org.apache.james.cli.ServerCmd --host <arg> <command>

 -h,--host <arg>   node hostname or ip address
 -p,--port <arg>   remote jmx agent port number
AddUser <username> <password>
RemoveUser <username>
ListUsers
```

Although I discovered that James quits some seconds after starting, I have jaxb jar file, I have put it in every lib folder there is to put.

Is there anything I am doing wrong? Am I to specify input mysql details and if so where, I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: Which version of JDK do you use?

Comment: 1.7/1.8/1.9, i tried using the three

Comment: Hi. Would you have any log file/stack trace to share with us?

Also, we are a bit more responsive on our gitter channel. Don't hesitate to check that out! https://gitter.im/apache/james-project

Comment: @Benwa thanks will check it out.